# Creating a new column in data frame of the position of the maximum value in that row, using R

Tags: r

I am trying to solve the following problem in R. I have a dataframe with different values per day, and I need to create a column that gives the day of the maximum value.
I am a beginner and have spent a long time trying to figure this out myself without much luck.

My date is in this format, as an example:

```
  D1 D2 D3 D4 D5
1  4  1 21  2  5
2  5  2 19  5  3
3  2 20  7  4  3
4  8 18  5  3  2
5  9  6 20  1  9
6 15  5  3  1 11
```

And I want to acheive this outcome, by adding an additional column:

```
  D1 D2 D3 D4 D5 Peak_day
1  4  1 21  2  5        3
2  5  2 19  5  3        3
3  2 20  7  4  3        2
4  8 18  5  3  2        2
5  9  6 20  1  9        3
6 15  5  3  1 11        1
```

The Peak_day column indicates the day or index where the highest value was for each row.
For example, for the first row, the highest value was 21 on D3, so Peak_day gives the value 3.

I have tried many different attempts but I am yet to be successful. For example:

```
peak <- function(vec){
  day_peak <- which(vec == max(vec))
  return(day_peak)}
df$Peak_day <- apply(df,1,peak)
```

I think I need to somehow vectorise the function but I've not been able to do this successfully.

Any solutions would be appreciated.
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get the position index of the max value for each row in a `vectorized` way

```
df1$Peak_day <- max.col(df1, 'first')
```

---

Or if we use the OP's method, then loop over the rows and use `which.max`

```
apply(df1, 1, which.max)
```

The issue with `which` is that it can return multiple index if there is a tie as we are using `==`.  But, it can be modified by selecting the first position if `[1]`

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(D1 = c(4L, 5L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 15L), D2 = c(1L, 2L, 
20L, 18L, 6L, 5L), D3 = c(21L, 19L, 7L, 5L, 20L, 3L), D4 = c(2L, 
5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L), D5 = c(5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 9L, 11L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```